# Is there an alternative for JTS TestBuilder on Linux?

Tags: linux, jts-topology-suite

**JTS Testbuilder**, an application for testing JTS functions, is available on Windows and I use it quite regularly. Are there anything like this on Linux? Does GEOS have anything similar to this on linux?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JTS Testbuilder is a java program: It works on linux as well. You only need to launch the `testbuilder.sh` file in the `jts-1.xx/bin` folder.

Comment: i installed JTS 1.11 from software center in ubuntu..where can i find this folder?

Comment: The command 'locate testbuilder.sh' will tell you where it is.

Comment: OK. apparently, when installing the ubuntu JTS package, the testbuilder.sh file is not present. Try to use a JTS downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/files/latest/download

Comment: i downloaded from the link you mentioned..now it works fine..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

Download and build JTS using Mavin (`sudo apt install maven`):

```
git clone https://github.com/locationtech/jts.git
cd jts
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Then start it like this:

```
./bin/testbuilder.sh &
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can download released JTS TestBuilder jar from below location:
https://github.com/locationtech/jts/releases

e.g. at the time of adding this answer, the latest one was: https://github.com/locationtech/jts/releases/download/jts-1.17.1/JTSTestBuilder.jar

and you can run it like:

```
java -jar -Xmx1024M -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel -jar JTSTestBuilder.jar
```